# Custom Date Time Formats in SQL Query

Tags: sql

I need to fetch the datetime value in this format 7/16/14 9:04 PM . Couldn't find any custom way to print a datetime in this way.

Please suggest.

Comment: Which database? Which version?

Comment: What RMDS are you using? (MYSQL,MSSQL,Oracle)

Comment: Please add the relevant tag for your DBMS. (In Oracle and Postgres you can use `to_char()` to format a date, other DBMS have similar functions). Check the manual of your database, you will find that this is actually documented there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In T-SQL you can get desired datetime format as:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 1)+ ' '+ 
+ Right(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 100),7)
AS [MM/DD/YY HH:MIAM (or PM)]
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/36806)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a similar table

```
CREATE TABLE myTab(
data DATETIME);

INSERT INTO myTab (data) VALUES ('2012-03-23 9:58');
INSERT INTO myTab (data) VALUES('2012-11-23 22:38');
INSERT INTO myTab (data) VALUES('2002-03-23 9:50');
```

can you use a similar query

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data, '%m/%d/%y %r') FROM myTab;
```

check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c42ba/1/0

Answer (score 0):

In `MSSQL` you could do something like

```
SELECT 
Convert(nvarchar(2), month(<YOUR_DATETIME_COLUMN>)) + '/' + Convert(nvarchar(2), day(<YOUR_DATETIME_COLUMN>)) + '/' + Convert(nvarchar(4), year(<YOUR_DATETIME_COLUMN>)) + ' ' +
Convert(nvarchar(2), datepart(hh, <YOUR_DATETIME_COLUMN>)) + ':' + RIGHT('0'+ CONVERT(nvarchar(2),datepart(mm, <YOUR_DATETIME_COLUMN>)), 2) + ' ' +
(CASE WHEN datepart(hh, <YOUR_DATETIME_COLUMN>) <= 12 THEN 'AM' ELSE 'PM' END)
```

IN `MySQL` it's nearly similar

```
SELECT 
Convert(nvarchar(2), month(<YOUR_DATETIME_COLUMN>)) + '/' + Convert(nvarchar(2), day(<YOUR_DATETIME_COLUMN>)) + '/' + Convert(nvarchar(4), year(<YOUR_DATETIME_COLUMN>)) + ' ' +
Convert(nvarchar(2), hour(<YOUR_DATETIME_COLUMN>)) + ':' + RIGHT('0'+ CONVERT(nvarchar(2),minute(<YOUR_DATETIME_COLUMN>)), 2) + ' ' +
(CASE WHEN hour(<YOUR_DATETIME_COLUMN>) <= 12 THEN 'AM' ELSE 'PM' END)
```